# Get values from BuildLog on UI or Text from UI

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can anyone help me, to get the values from UI, which is a log, so they would not have static web elements,

I would like to get the values '0' and '800' and Differnce values, from log, by looking at the text 'CIA_StartTansportCost'

```
<div id="node_13646" class="leaf ch_13642 ch_13596 ch_13245">    
   <div id="msg_13646" class="msg l4">    
     <u id="ts_13646" class="ts">    
       <u class="ts_in">[12:48:59]</u>    
     </u>    
     <i class="mark error_msg actual status_err">    
       <i class="parent">[CIA_StartTransportCost] </i>    
       800    
     </i>    
</div>    
</div>    
<div id="node_13647" class="leaf ch_13642 ch_13596 ch_13245">    
<div id="msg_13647" class="msg l4">    
  <u id="ts_13647" class="ts">    
    <u class="ts_in">[12:48:59]</u>    
  </u>    
  <i class="mark error_msg stdout multiline ">    
    <i class="parent">[CIA_StartTransportCost] </i>    
    [Test Output] Running: "CIA_StartTransportCost", Expected Result: 0, Actual      Result: 800, Difference: 80000.000000%, Test Threshold : 0.99, Test Result : FAIL, ExecutionSuccess : True RowsAffected: 1
    </i>    
  </div>    
</div>
```